# How expensive is it to pass around SPListItem objects?

Tags: development, performance, service-application, resources

I'm working on a service application to keep lists in different site collections in sync.  Part of what is going to happen is that, when an item is updated in any of the lists, an event receiver is going to call the service and pass it the updated SPListItem, so that the service can then update the other lists.

My question arises from the fact that I need to account for the possibility that the item's title might be what is updated.  If the item's title changes, the service won't be able to find the correct list items on the other lists.  (I can't rely on the item's list ID or unique ID to find the same item in all the lists, so it's gonna have to be title.)

I have a strategy to save a "copy" of the list item (as an SPListItem object) before it gets updated so that I can compare it with the updated SPListItem object, and tell if the title has changed.  But... where should I make the comparison?

From a "good coding" perspective, I want to push that logic all the way into the service application.  But that means for every update, even one where the title does not change, the service client will have to pass two SPListItem objects to the service.  If that's expensive, I could alternatively move the title comparison logic into the client, and if the title has changed, pass just the old title as a string along with the updated SPListItem.

So... how expensive is it to pass an SPListItem to a service?  Can I get away with passing two every time, or should I only pass the minimum information required for the service to do it's job?

Comment: Side note: have you considered using a guid in a hidden list column on both lists to avoid title comparison? Multiple list items can have the same title, they aren't guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Store an "Origin ID" as a hidden column in the foreign list, then you can match on the ID. Nice n simple. @RJ Cuthbertson - crossed the post - same idea.

Comment: Either ideas works, but I suppose implementation would be dependent on whether this was a one-way sync or a two-way sync.

Comment: @RJ Cuthbertson & Paul Leigh -- not sure that I can do that.  The content types / lists that need to be synced are from a 3rd party SharePoint add on.  The whole reason we need to sync them is that they did not plan well for architectures that required more than one site collection.  We need to have more than one site collection for scalability (expecting well over 4TB content...eventually).  But since it's someone else's content type, I'm reluctant to modify it.

Comment: @RJCuthbertson, it's an all-way sync (there will be more than just two lists), or at least that's what I'm shooting for.  I thought about having a "master list" that pushed changes out to the other lists, but trying for an all-way sync seems more challenging, and therefore enticing.  :)

Comment: I wouldn't modify the content type, but lists can have columns outside of the content types used with them. If it's an all way sync you're going to need a unique identifier of some kind on every item, however you decide to do that.

Comment: While such a solution might be fun to code, it is almost never in the best interests of the client/customer to have 3 "master" lists that contain the same data as it generally leads to all kinds of confusion for end users.  From a developer, it could also become an instant nightmare if your sync process stops working for a few days and you must now try to figure out what the 'right' data is to push where, especially if it has been modified in more than one list while your process was stopped. If it were me, I'd really look at rethinking this approach

Comment: @DaveWise, I wasn't thinking of it so much as having multiple master lists, but more along the lines of: if I'm a user and I need to add or edit an item in one of those lists, I can just go to the list on the site where I'm already working, and then the service will propagate the change to have it available on the other sites.  As opposed to, I'm working in site A, but I need to remember to navigate over to site B to add a new list item, because that's where the master list is.  Your point about what might happen if the service drops is a good one though. I will be rethinking how to do this.